# How does next.js/react create page from a headless cms

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby, next.js

I am new to using headless cms and was wondering how to render content as a new page? I am building the site in Next.js and comfortable.io but I don't understand how making a new page in comfortable can be passed to the next.js project to produce the pages. Can someone please point me in the correct direction for what I need to learn to understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data off your headless CMS you will have to hit the API endpoints provided. In order to render the CMS content on the server side you will have to do your get request to the API in the `getInitialProps` life cycle method. 
After doing so next.js will render the page along with the fetched content to the client.

You can find more information in [the documentation link here.](https://nextjs.org/docs#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)